# What is happening with the https migration?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Many of the other StackExchange sites have migrated to https. When is Judaism's turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in progress.  HTTPS has been supported on main for a while but you aren't automatically switched if you use HTTP.  But did you notice that when you came to meta you were automatically switched over to HTTPS?  Once you're there you'll stay there if you use regular site navigation.

According to the [migration plan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/162102), the next step is to switch incoming HTTP over to HTTPS.  As far as I know this will be done across the network at the same time.  SE has been using SO and Meta.SE to test out some parts of the migration, but all the per-site metas are HTTPS now (check out the new meta URL pattern, by the way), so I have no reason to doubt that when it comes time to do this next step, it'll be for everybody.